# PHP: prevent folder hacking - if path has ../ in it?

Tags: php, path

i'm doing a simple thingy in php and i wonder how i can test if the variable $path contains the following structure ../

so i'll simply have a ?path=somepath structure in my url, and if anybody would enter ../ it allows him to go one directory up. I know of course that that's not the best solution, however for my little thingy it's enough if i just test the $path variable for a string of "../" in it. if so die();

i'm not sure what's the best way to test that!

regards matt

Comment: for what purpose you are using such a path?

Comment: @mathi I am confused why you are sending `?path=url` instead of just the actual URL in a link. Its opening can of security worms I tell you.

Comment: because I'm building kind of a filbrowser who reads my files on my server. one file contains the whole userinterface. the $path sets the folderpath which folder is currently viewed in my filebrowser. i can't just set the actual URL, doesn't make sense for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer your question:

```
if(strpos($path,'../') !== false){
  // looks like someone 's trying to hack here - simply
  // do nothing (or send an email-notification to yourself
  // to be informed and see how often this happens)
}else{
  // here comes the magic

}
```

but: you really shouldn't do so. if you want an easy solution, use a switch-statement for every possible $path and include the relevant file (or whatever you have to do).

Comment: @RobertPitt: i don't want to offend somebody - i hope it's better now ;)

Comment: Replace down vote with +, its not offending to myself but others will find it unneeded for that post :), happy days

Comment: thank you. how could i test if the $path just starts with a slash? like ?path=/anything. actually in this case i wanna call a die(); however if ?path=anything/anything it should work.

Comment: egads.. I am imagining a switch statement for every path on most CMS systems.. how nightmarish... `RewriteMap` is waaaay easier.

Comment: i'm doing it like this now: if (substr($path, 0, 1) == "/" || substr($path, 0, 1) == "" || substr($path, 0, 2) == "./" || substr($path, 0, 3) == "../") { ...maybe there is an easier way, but it works.

Comment: talking to "hacker" is the stupidest thing a developer can do, no matter the language

Answer (score 12):

Instead of doing that, you could just call `realpath()` on it and check if the path it's supposed to be in is a prefix of that.

Even better, why not keep a whitelist and reject anything not in it?

Answer (score 0):

I's an alternative solution that allow you to customize the url....

```
<?php
$arr= array(
  "register" => "register.php",
  "login" => "userlogin.php",
  "admin" => "adminlogin.php",
  "etc" => "otherpage.php",
  );
if ( isset ( $_GET['path'] )    
    if ( array_key_exists( $_GET['path'] , $arr) ){
      //do some stuff... 
      include( $arr[$_GET['path']] );
    }
    else
      echo 'Page Not Found!';          
else
  echo 'Required Field Empty!';       
?>
```

So calling `index.php?path=admin` page `adminlogin.php` will be included....

Comment: also make sure you have register_globals switched off if your useing < php 5.2, this is exploitable under those settings `index.php?arr[ihack]=../../../&path=ihack`

Comment: not really.. because (if php configured fine) `index.php?arr[ihack]=....` could be accessible by php only from `$_GET['arr']`... and `$arr` in php script wouldn't be replaced....

Comment: thats going to be a terrible mess to maintain such a list

Comment: sorry, but tell me how SQL hit the nail on the head... I really don't understand....

Comment: relax, it was just an ignorant comment

Comment: @marcx yes, it is possible to lose your database through `$_GET` see http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: @Talvi I never said that you can't lose db through $_GET. 1) sql doesn't belong to the arguments of this discussion. 2) if SQL was part of this discussion you simply use `mysql_real_escape_string` to sanitize the input and all the problems disapper :D

Comment: @marcx true - I was simply trying to point out other dangers of unsanitized input. my comment can be disregarded.

Answer (score 0):

one of the easier ways is to harden your `php.ini` config, specifically the [open_basedir directive](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/06/php-open_basedir-in-phpini-to-limit-php-file-accesses-to-a-certain-directory.html). Keep in mind, some CMS systems do actually use `..\` quite a bit in the code, and when there are includes outside the root folder this can create problems. (i.e. pear modules)

Another method is to use [mod_rewrite](http://www.ice2o.com/secure_php.php).

Unless you are using an include file to check each and every URL for injection from `$_GET` and `$_SERVER['request_uri']` variables, you will open doors for this kind of attack. for example, you might protect `index.php` but not `submit.php`. This is why hardening `php.ini` and `.htaccess` is the preferred method.

Comment: there is no difference between `index.php?arr=?>DROP TABLE` and /item/DROP TABLE/`. go figure